# CSS Grid with meta viewport causing html and body to be under sized

Tags: css

I am trying to build a really simple CSS Grid Layout: header/content/footer. I had it working, then I tried opening it up in device emulator and I could not understand the behavior at all. To make matters worse it *also* did not behave as expected on my phone, but it behaved *differently* than in the device emulator.

In the emulator the page loads as I expected: the Body formed a grid with a header, the main content overflowed on the x axis so the whole page had a horizontal scroll bar, and the footer was flush with the bottom of the page. When I removed the class that made the main content oversized it looked pretty nice! Then when I added it back in the html and body in the element inspector suddenly were a small portion of the screen and the footer was flush with that bottom, the whole page scrolled left and right, and there was a giant empty space at the bottom of the actual view.

[image: An example of the rendering quirk I don't understand]

The red box above shows the empty space. The blue box on the same screenshot shows where the element inspector claimed the html and body elements were. On my phone (iPhone 13 Pro, Safari), I get more or less the expected behavior, but the window chrome hides the footer, so I have to scroll and I can't make it go away. I have to assume that if I had a smaller physical device to test it on the behavior would be the same...To add another mystery: *sometimes* after I've had it open it will load straight into the weirdly resized mode.

I stripped it down to the simplest I could make it and then added a few buttons to demonstrate the behavior. The [code is here](https://github.com/Crisfole/crisfole.github.com/blob/master/css-quirk.html), and it's up [live here](http://crisfole.github.io/css-quirk.html).

I know this is some sort of interaction between the `<meta viewport>` and what `100vh` and `100vw` means...but I really, really don't understand what's going on. I know how to get my code working mostly the way I want it. An acceptable answer will explain what I'm seeing in the emulator. To phrase it as a question: "What is going on in the emulator that causes this strange re-sizing?"

### EDIT

It looks like the initial rendering depends on the previous state of the page. If you reload the demo above when the section is not oversized it renders as in the first screenshot. If you reload the demo when the screenshot *is* oversized it initially renders as in the final screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is in the viewport meta. Try adding `initial-scale=1` - this will set the initial zoom level of the page (device-width).

My guess is the zoom happens because changing overflow to anything but visible creates a new [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context) - causing the initial state to be re-evaluated. At the point of re-evaluation, the content exceeds the viewport why the width is considered to be 960px (iOS default) - triggering the zoom to fit.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem, but I'm not sure I can explain it properly since I'm not an expert or specialist. I actually spent more than an hour inspecting your code, trying different solutions, and reading some related research.

1- I noticed that you use `rem` unit to resize **elements** NOT **font** but when I research it, I found most if not all results relate `rem` with `root element` and `font-size`. so I was wondering if we can use `rem` to size element and kept searching about and found that it's possible, but I couldn't find enough details about this specific part.

Even on [mdn web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units), it says "**the rem unit means "The root element's font-size" (rem stands for "root em").**"

2- Anyway, in your code, I changed `50rem` to `80%` and the problem disappeared in the emulator and everywhere.

I hope my effort helps.

```js
function toggleContentOverflow() {
    const isOn = document.body.classList.toggle("content-overflow");
    contentOverflow.textContent = isOn ? "On" : "Off";
  }

  function toggleMainScroll() {
    const isOn = document.body.classList.toggle("overflow-scroll");
    overflowScroll.textContent = isOn ? "On" : "Off";
  }
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
}
header, main, footer {
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
}
main {
  padding-block-start: 0;
  padding-block-end: 0;
}
header, footer {
  background-color: #ffe;
}
header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
footer {
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
}
section {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 2rem;
  margin: 2rem auto;
}

body.content-overflow section {
  width: 80%;
}

body.overflow-scroll main {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<body class="content-overflow">
<header>
  Header Content
</header>
<main>
  <section>
    <h1>Too Large Card</h1>
  </section>
  <aside style='margin-top: 1em'>
    <button type="button" onclick="toggleContentOverflow(event)">"section { width: 80%; }" <span id="contentOverflow">On</span></button>
  </aside>
  <aside style='margin-top: 1em'>
    <button type="button" onclick="toggleMainScroll(event)">"main { overflow: scroll }" <span id="overflowScroll">Off</span></button>
  </aside>
  <p>
    To see this quirk:
  </p>
  <ol>
    <li>Open this page in private mode (to avoid extensions inserting elements).</li>
    <li>Open the developer tools</li>
    <li>Turn on the device emulator</li>
    <li>refresh the page</li>
    <li>Click the 'section { width: var(--size-15); }' button.</li> 
  </ol>
</main>
<footer>
  Footer Content
</footer>
</body>
```

Comment: It makes sense that 80% width stops the issue. It doesn't overflow if the width is only 80% of the total width ;)